# Creating custom Object Array and Storing Socket, for later Retrieval.

Tags: java, android, sockets

If I have created class like this,

```
public class UserManagement{
    Socket clientSocket;
    public UserManagement(Socket soc,String usrN){
        clientSocket = soc;
    }

  }
```

The application needs to maintain multiple clients,

So Every  time it accepts a connection with

```
 ServerSocket ser = new ServerSocket(1234);
 Socket soc = ser.accept();
```

Will an array of UserManagement class, handle the socket.

I mean will it be possible to create an array and access the sockets individually.

Is that possible? I am not asking for advice to develop multithreaded client handler instead I'm asking if it is possible or not.

If yes what are PreCautions I will need to take.

Comment: This will work. There is nothing special in it.

Comment: I thought, that the socket might just get lost in an attempt to maintain array

Comment: A socket is just a handle for some OS network resources. The contained data stay valid as long as you stay in your context. For example it's not possible to store serialized versions and use them in other program instances. But inside your process they stay valid. Even if your program forks both copies keep valid sockets.

Comment: Thanks, that cleared my confsion